# BS modal timeout when button click in dynamic created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap modal for quick shop purpose. When clicking a button I've added a small timeout function to let the modal load everything before it shows up. Just for usabillity. 
This works perfectly when clicking the button inside a normal plain div/element.

The problem I'm facing is that it doesn't work when clicking a button inside a *dynamic* created div/element. 
I have a carousel (owl-carousel) with several items in it and each item has a quick shop button. 
When clicking this button the modal pops up but skips the loading part. So what happens is that when opening one modal and closing it and then open a next modal the content from the first modal is displayed and after a few seconds the content of the new modal is displayed.

It looks like the loading part of the script is skipped when clicking on a dynamic created element/div/button.

What I have is this:

```
// dynamic created items inside owl-carousel//
<div class="item">
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-shop-modal" data-vid="12384069" data-handle="12384069.html">Quick shop</a>
</div>

// the modal //
    <div id="loader"></div>
      <div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="quick-shop-modal" class="modal fade" data-show="false">
    .....
    </div>

// The script //
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on('click', '.quickview', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#loader').show();
            var url = $(this).data('handle') + '/?format=json';
            var vid = $(this).data('vid');
            var $target = $($(this).data('target'));

            // it looks like this part is skipped
            $target.data('triggered',true);
            setTimeout(function() {
              if ($target.data('triggered')) {
                quick_shop(url, vid);
              };
                }, 1000);
              return false;
            });
          });
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a callback function instead of a fixed timeout duration.

Comment: Do you have an example then? The problem is that the server I'm using is way too fast :) When openening a popup everything goes too fast which isn't ideal or looking smooth.